# OpenCV error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Tags: python, opencv

Код должен приводить к захвату видео с камеры (скопировал с opencv docs), однако возникает ошибка.

Код:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture()

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) % 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Ошибка:

> ```
> File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
> gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
> cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не задали *номер камеры* - первая (или единая) камера имеет номер `0`.

И так вместо

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
```

напишите

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

---

Примечание:

Не надо скобок в команде `while` в Питоне, можно просто писать `while True:`

Вместо

```
cv2.waitKey(1) % 0xFF
```

нужно использовать

```
cv2.waitKey(1) % 0x100
```

или - лучше - гораздо быстрейшую побитовую операцию `&`:

```
cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

так как результат не тот-же сам.