# Ошибка "(-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty()" при чтении иконки с помощью OpenCV

Tags: python

```
import cv2;from PIL import Image,ImageTk


up_icon=cv2.imread('C:/Users/user/Desktop/shift_up.ico')
up_icon=cv2.resize(up_icon,(200,200),interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
up_icon=cv2.cvtColor(up_icon,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
up_icon=Image.fromarray(up_icon)
up_icon=ImageTk.PhotoImage(up_icon)
```

Ошибка:

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4045: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

shift_up.ico - это картинка с размерами 128x128 пикселей

проблема точно не в установке размеров,потому что когда я убрал строку с cv2.resize(),он всё равно выдал ту же самую ошибку,только уже ругался он на следующую строку

P.S.(Переименование в формат jpg не работает)

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/881957/opencv-error-215assertion-failed-src-empty-in-function-cvcvtcolor?rq=1), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/991094/Ошибка-215assertion-failed-empty-in-function-cvcascadeclassifierdete?rq=1), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144205/Ошибка-215assertion-failed-ssize-empty-in-function-cvresize), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265187/error-opencv4-1-0-error-215assertion-failed-ssize-empty-in-function), ..., [5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profit).

Comment: Спасибо за большое количество ссылок,но VideoCapture не работает,а остальные ссылки мало чем относятся к моей проблеме,например,во второй ссылке у него были проблемы именно с CascadeClassifier,и подсказали ему именно исправление проблемы,связанной с использованием этого класса.